# Simple SQL AND OR Not Working

Tags: sql, boolean-logic

```
SELECT *
FROM Items
WHERE (Balance >= 0) OR (Item Like '%XF%' AND Balance > 0)
```

This is returning all items with a `balance >= 0`.

I need it to report all items with a `balance >=0` OR...
all items with a `balance > 0` (but not equal to 0) and have 'XF' in the item number.

```
Item 1234 - Balance 0
Item 1234 - Balance 25    
Item 1234-XF - Balance 25    
Item 1234-XF - Balance 0 <-- should not be here because it is an XF and has a balance of 0.
```

Why doesn't this work?  It does work if I do each individually, so I'm not sure why  I can't combine the two.

Comment: Not sure I'm following the problem. Can you share some sample data, the result you're actually getting for it, and the result you're trying to get? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It's doing what you're asking it to do. If `Balance > 0` is true, then `Balance >= 0` must be true, and whether `Item Like '%XF%'` is true or not doesn't matter.

I think you actually want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Items 
WHERE (Balance > 0) 
   OR (Item Not Like '%XF%' AND Balance = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the exists operator here.

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE A
WHERE balance >=0 AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE 
WHERE A.BALANCE =0 AND A.ITEM  LIKE'%-XF').
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

With an OR statement in general the first statement is evaluated first and if it is true, the second statement will not be considered and in this case that record will be deemed to match the logic and be returned. The nature of your expression: (Balance >= 0) OR (Item Like '%XF%' AND Balance > 0) means that if the first is false then the second will never be true.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE (Item Like '%XF%' AND Balance > 0) OR (Balance = 0)
```

Comment: Given OP's clarification the correct answer is given by Blorgbeard below.

Answer (score -1):

The SQL statement has a good and working result except for one value, which is `XF = 0`. According to the statement, it should not be there because you want only XF greater then 0.

Maybe you can try

```
WHERE (Balance >= 0) OR (Item Like '%XF%' AND Balance >= 1)
```

Remember that 0.01 is also greater than 0